# Consume Laravel service from existing CodeIgniter app

Tags: php, codeigniter, laravel-5.1

I have the following issue:

I have an existing web app built with CodeIgniter, it works well. There are new features to be developed, some of them have to do with emails and notifications.  I I have worked with Laravel, and its my framework of choice for new apps.

So, what I'm thinking is ... Maybe I could set a service with Laravel, that handle's email queues and notifications, maybe set up events, but how can a consume the service from CodeIgniter ?? That is the issue.

Additionally, is this an good approach ? Could it be done ? Any suggestions ?

Thanks. =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make a simple API with the Laravel app to receive emails, queue them, and send them. I wouldn't personally do this. Since you're having to make API calls from Codeigniter anyway, I would just use a service like https://www.mailgun.com/ (or one of many other similar services) and skip Laravel entirely.

You can use something like Guzzle in CI to make POST requests to Laravel.

```
use GuzzleHttp\Client;
use GuzzleHttp\Message\Request;
use GuzzleHttp\Message\Response;

$client = new Client();
$response = $client->post("http://api.yourlaravel.app/sendemail", [
//Change POST request info here to be your email data
    'headers' => ['X-Foo' => 'Bar'],
    'body'    => ['field_name' => 'value']
]);
var_dump($response->getStatusCode()); //verify the POST request returned ok
```

There are several tutorials on writing an API with Laravel, including a series on Laracasts about it that I highly recommend. They will show you how to receive this POST request in Laravel.

Comment: Hi @Brynn Bateman, the CI app is used in a corporate environment, it's obviously web but there not going to get mailgun. Right now the CI is spaghetti code, I tried to do some work on top of it, but for the new requirements, email, events, notifications and jobs I want to do it with Laravel. I wanted to know how the two might communicate, cURL, http, I don't know, I'm clueless right now as what to try out.

Comment: Hi Andres - I updated my answer for you. Easiest would be to have CI use a package like Guzzle to make POST requests to your Laravel app, and to write a simple API with your Laravel app to receive the POST requests.

Comment: Great !! I'll check it out. I got the Laravel part, I've done many api's, just had a few doubts with CI. Thanks !

Comment: There is probably a more elegant way to do the CI part, I don't use CI so I don't know, but the premise will be the same regardless of how you do it.